# Detecting all shortcuts to execute in certain path

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I'm trying to execute installed programs with text command. After a research I've found out how to find all the installed programs.
What I need is getting all .lnk files from those 2 paths and execute them with their names as command

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

I already have a command textbox which doing other things. Only problem is I have no idea how to find shortcuts and execute them by their names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) to, well, get all the files in a directory. Then loop through the files and run them with [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

```
string path = @"c:\";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach(string file in files) {
    Process.Start(file);
}
```

This example assumes you want to start every file in the given path. You'll need to do your own checks for extensions.